# Use .net project with Eclipse on MAC with VisualStudio On line

Tags: asp.net, eclipse, macos, visual-studio

Can I work on a project stored in Visual Studio on Line using Eclipse on OSX?

Comment: See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875910/is-it-feasible-to-do-net-development-using-eclipse)

Comment: But Work with on OSX system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I know. Visual Studio online is a browser based environment, so if your question is if you can use it to develop .NET on mac - as an environment - I think it would work. But you won't be developing MAC apps on that.

do you with to develop MAC OS applications using .NET? if so, have you tried Mono Project (http://www.mono-project.com/)?

btw, I think mono is now Xamarin  (http://xamarin.com/)