# Which is a better IDE Visual Studio or Eclipse

Tags: c#, java, c++, visual-studio, eclipse

I have noticed a trend in Coop programs in the universities in my area at least.  They are teaching using eclipse as an IDE, instead of Visual Studios.  My company uses almost exclusively Visual Studios, but I have used both.

I am curious about whether the switch to eclipse at the university level is also prevalent in the workplace, or whether Visual Studios is still king?

Which do you prefer and why?

Comment: Feature comparison: [Eclipse vs. Visual Studio: What are the features in Eclipse that are not present in Visual Studio and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977467/eclipse-vs-visual-studio-what-are-the-features-in-eclipse-that-are-not-present)

Comment: Might want to take this to Programmers.SE? (Not sure if even that is the right place for it, but SO definitely isn't.)

Comment: I use each for different languages.

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and guess that the Eclipse shift has something to do with the price tag....:) in college I used Eclipse too until my College gave me an ACM Student membership and we were allowed to legally download VS.

Comment: @Cpfohl: MS has MSDNAA... also free for academic use.

Comment: @Mehrad: yup, but my school wasn't set up with MS, so it would have been a pain to prove I was a student.

Answer (score 2):

There are different reasons for why Visual Studio Vs Eclipse

1. Visual Studio is commercial product and Eclipse is more of a freeware
2. Visual Studio is more friendly to .NET world and Eclipse is for JAVA, its not to say that   totally we can not is vice versa
3. Visual Studio is more rich IDE in terms of feature wise, per se debugging, editing compare to Eclispe
4. Visual Studio provide lots of out of the Box stuff which reduces the development time and makes developer's life easy.
5. Of course there are lot of other reasons why one will go with VS or Eclise (as few companies are JAVA platform or .NET platform apps)

Answer (score 1):

For a Windows shop using only Microsoft compiler, there is no reason to use anything else but Visual Studio (with Visual Assist X).

Using Eclipse will keep your mind open to the cross-platform possibility.

However, I think that Eclipse is not a good cross-platform IDE for C++. QtCreator is a much better versus for Visual Studio (C++ only).