# C# plugin for Eclipse

Tags: c#, linux, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there a good working plugin for C# in Eclipse? I'm using a Linux machine so I do not have access to Visual Studio Express. I already have an Eclipse Environment working perfectly for my needs so I don't want to deal with multiple IDEs if at all possible. It doesn't need code complete but highlighting and compiling would be nice.

Comment: wrt: "not that i would use it ever again" you're missing out. VS2010 is the b's knees.

Comment: VS2010 is very slick, seriously it makes Eclipse look like nothing.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145484/looking-for-up-to-date-eclipse-plugin-for-c

Comment: I used to use it... in fact the dev license is sitting on my desk collecting dust. I did some tests between eclipse with gcc vs VS2010 and the EXEs were 10x smaller than VS2010... plus it's not cross-platform, and my dev team consists of 2 macs, 4 ubuntus, and 1 windows.

Comment: Advertising VS2010 here is quite unnecessary since the author has stated that he/she does NOT have access to Visual Studio Express since he/she is working on a Linux machine. When you get VS2010 up and running on Linux (even with some overhead), give me a call...

As for the question - sadly all at least to me known Mono C# Eclipse plugins are extremely outdated. You can however maybe try some tweaking using custom makefiles in Eclipse and make it possible to compile C# code from there but you will have to accept the absence of almost everything a modern IDE offers for a specific language.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Emonic is an actual eclipse plugin for C#: http://emonic.sourceforge.net/.

Here's a handy guide for how to get it set up: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-migratenetvs/

Monodevelop is great, but won't meet your requirement not to have to work in multiple IDEs.

Comment: Is this really a valid Answer?  The Question required an answer that would work in a Linux environment. The "migratenetvs" link states that only windows is supported. Quote - ".NET V2.0 SDK — This means you must work in a Windows environment. "

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure about eclipse, but MonoDevelop is cross platform.

http://monodevelop.com/

Answer (score 3):

From:
http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_For_Linux_Developers#Eclipse_in_C.23_Mode

- [Black-Sun](http://black-sun.sourceforge.net/)
- [Emonic](http://emonic.sourceforge.net/)
- [eSharp](http://www.improve-technologies.com/alpha/esharp/)

I don't personally have any experience with the mentioned plugins.  Any C# development I've done on Linux has been through [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)

Comment: All these projects seem to be dead. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

From Eclipse marketplace:

[**aCute:** C# edition in Eclipse IDE](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/acute-c-edition-eclipse-ide)

aCute enables C# application development in the Eclipse IDE.

aCute provides a rich C# editor with error reporting, hover, content assist, jump to references... (using OmniSharp) and syntax highlighting (using TextMate grammar).

aCute also integrates various operations of the `dotnet` command-line (New, Run, Test, Publish) as typical Eclipse IDE wizards and workflows.

aCute provide supports debugging for .NET applications.