# How to use Eclipse for C# coding

Tags: c#, eclipse

I have used Microsoft Visual Studio C# 2010 Express for my project in C#. Now after completion of my project, I have to verify my project on my company's software for code review, which is build on Eclipse. I am the first one here to run C# code on that IDE. Please help.

Comment: Possible Dulpicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444625/c-sharp-plugin-for-eclipse

Comment: If there's going to be any amount of C# done in the company, they should really embrace Visual Studio for it. It's going to prove a *much* nicer experience for everyone involved.

Comment: @Safeer, I have seen that link

Comment: @JonSkeet, actually i have made my project in visual studio itself. It just requires a testing now, which is to be done on Eclipse IDE

Comment: @user2515053: Why? Why would *testing* require an IDE? What is going to be done with the IDE itself? Do they need to debug the project? Surely you need to test the actual project binary. Really, this is only asking for pain. I'm not aware of any *mature* C# plugins for Eclipse.