# How to use eclipse for C# development?

Tags: c#, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to use eclipse for C# development?
If so, how to do it? What's your preferred combination?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145484/looking-for-up-to-date-eclipse-plugin-for-c-sharp

Comment: I've never heard that before. Why would you like to do that? I think you can write C# codes in eclipse, but they can not be compiled unless there are plug-ins for compiling

Answer (score 13):

While I've seen a few partially-baked plugins, I don't believe there's anything which comes even *close* to the Java tooling within Eclipse.

If you're on Windows you'd be best off using Visual Studio. If you're on another platform, either use a VM and Visual Studio, use [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

Whilst I'd love there to be good C# support in Eclipse (and at one point I *considered* trying to do such a thing myself) the reality is that it's just not there at the moment.

Comment: do we still have MonoDevelop for window, please confirm as I can't see a link to download the setup.

Comment: @RollerCosta: http://www.monodevelop.com/download/ ("For Mac and Windows, you can download Xamarin Studio which is a bundle of MonoDevelop along with Xamarin iOS/Android plugins and branding.")

Comment: @Jon Skeet : You might want to try JetBrains Rider. Works with .NET Core 1.1. And on Linux. It's more there than MonoDevelop at the moment. But for .NET Core 2.0, it's still in EAP. Somehow, the monodevelop asp.net plugin doesn't compile at the moment.

Comment: @StefanSteiger: Well yes, there are a lot more options than there were 6 years ago when I answered this. (Visual Studio code springs to mind too, of course...) But my June comment was specifically answering RollerCosta's question about whether MonoDevelop was still available for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Use VisualStudio Express if you want a free IDE. Or even [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/). Plugins on Eclipse do not come close for C# / .Net development. If you are on Mono, try [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) or, again, SharpDevelop.

Comment: do we still have MonoDevelop for window, please confirm as I can't see a link to download the setup.