# Anyway To Code C# in Eclipse?

Tags: c#, eclipse, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

So right now I use Visual Studio for my C# programming, however I was wondering if there is a way to switch to Eclipse. The only reason I want to (and this may seem like a silly reason to switch...) is because I like the look of the Console in Eclipse, and the way the output text looks.

If there is anyway to run a C# program in Eclipse, or get the output console that Eclipse has, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: @PradeepSimha Thanks for that. When I try to install the plugin through Eclipse, it gives me an error, saying: org.emonic.debugger_feature.feature.group [0.0.2] cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.

Comment: Then please post that as a new question :)

Comment: @PradeepSimha Thanks, it worked! My error was that the EmonicDebugger was for Linux Eclipse versions only!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question has already been answered in this thread on stackoverflow

[How to use eclipse for C# development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803033/how-to-use-eclipse-for-c-sharp-development)

I'm pretty certain eclipse is only for java and c++, and as far as I know the only IDE for c# is visual studios.

I also like the console in eclipse!

Comment: I take back what I said about visual studios being the only IDE for c#, I forgot about Mono, and there are probably some other less popular ones as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with c# in eclipse with thrid party plugins. But i as understand eclipse is more used for Java, C/C++ and not for c#.

Comment: This statement is false, Eclipse is designed to work for virtually any language as long as correct plugin is available. Correct answer would be as of now no 100% perfect plugin is available.

Comment: @PradeepSimha: Agreed but out of certain plugins available nobody is even close to plugins/ support available for Java, c .. plugins. I have mentioned same thing in above post.